# Loupedeck USB device 'libvirtd' pass to Win with UDEV rule

Tags: qemu, libvirt, usb-device

I have [this console](https://loupedeck.com/products/loupedeck-plus/) that I'm trying to pass as an USB to the Win11 running on QEMU.
It is unhappy being 'redirected' as an USB device, so I wrote an UDEV rule for it, b/c without it, of course I didn't have permissions:

rule:

```
$udevadm info --attribute-walk --path=$(udevadm info --query=path --name=/dev/ttyACM0)

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c3:00.3/usb1/1-1/1-1>
    KERNEL=="ttyACM0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c3:00.3/usb1/>
    KERNELS=="1-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="cdc_acm"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
    ATTRS{bmCapabilities}=="6"
    ATTRS{iad_bFirstInterface}=="00"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{iad_bFunctionSubClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{iad_bInterfaceCount}=="02"
    ATTRS{physical_location/dock}=="no"
    ATTRS{physical_location/horizontal_position}=="left"
    ATTRS{physical_location/lid}=="no"
    ATTRS{physical_location/panel}=="top"
    ATTRS{physical_location/vertical_position}=="upper"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c3:00.3/usb1/>
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="ef"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="02"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="7"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="2ec2"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Loupedeck"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{physical_location/dock}=="no"
    ATTRS{physical_location/horizontal_position}=="left"
    ATTRS{physical_location/lid}=="no"
    ATTRS{physical_location/panel}=="top"
    ATTRS{physical_location/vertical_position}=="upper"
    ATTRS{power/active_duration}=="460164"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend}=="2"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="2000"
    ATTRS{power/connected_duration}=="460164"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/level}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/persist}=="1"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="459880"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{product}=="Loupedeck+"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{remove}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="15"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c3:00.3/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0605"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 6.5.13-4-MANJARO xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="5"
    ATTRS{power/active_duration}=="988097"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/connected_duration}=="4021177"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/level}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="988083"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="3033090"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{remove}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:c3:00.3"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{tx_lanes}=="1"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="209"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c3:00.3':
    KERNELS=="0000:c3:00.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{current_link_speed}=="16.0 GT/s PCIe"
    ATTRS{current_link_width}=="16"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x15b9"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="43"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-15"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ffff"
    ATTRS{max_link_speed}=="16.0 GT/s PCIe"
    ATTRS{max_link_width}=="16"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_irqs/43}=="msi"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="4005320"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="16486"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="enabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}=="1"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}=="1"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}=="39380"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}=="105"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}=="105"
    ATTRS{power_state}=="D0"
    ATTRS{remove}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rescan}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{reset}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{reset_method}=="pm"
    ATTRS{resource0}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x00"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x8b75"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x103c"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1022"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:08.1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="pcieport"
    ATTRS{ari_enabled}=="0"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x060400"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{current_link_speed}=="16.0 GT/s PCIe"
    ATTRS{current_link_width}=="16"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x14eb"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="2"
    ATTRS{irq}=="36"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-15"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="ffff"
    ATTRS{max_link_speed}=="16.0 GT/s PCIe"
    ATTRS{max_link_width}=="16"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_irqs/36}=="msi"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{power/autosuspend_delay_ms}=="100"
    ATTRS{power/control}=="on"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="4021811"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="active"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup}=="disabled"
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_abort_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_active_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_expire_count}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_last_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_max_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power/wakeup_total_time_ms}==""
    ATTRS{power_state}=="D0"
    ATTRS{remove}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{rescan}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{reset}=="(not readable)"
    ATTRS{reset_method}=="pm"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x00"
    ATTRS{secondary_bus_number}=="195"
    ATTRS{subordinate_bus_number}=="195"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x14eb"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1022"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1022"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
    ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
    ATTRS{waiting_for_supplier}=="0"
```

with forementioned rule, I can run VM with this USB added as host device with config:

```
<hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
  <source>
    <vendor id="0x2ec2"/>
    <product id="0x0002"/>
  </source>
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
</hostdev>
```

the address fits the one from `lsblk`.

`ls` points to the right device and it has correct permissions (the parent):

```
ll /dev/loupeLoupe                                               
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 dec 17 23:40 /dev/loupeLoupe -> bus/usb/001/007
```

udev test says:

```
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:c3:00.3/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
DEVNAME=/dev/ttyACM0
MAJOR=166
MINOR=0
ACTION=add
SUBSYSTEM=tty
TAGS=:systemd:
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=Loupedeck+
ID_MODEL_ENC=Loupedeck+
ID_MODEL_ID=0002
ID_SERIAL=Loupedeck_Loupedeck+
ID_VENDOR=Loupedeck
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Loupedeck
ID_VENDOR_ID=2ec2
ID_REVISION=0100
ID_TYPE=generic
ID_USB_MODEL=Loupedeck+
ID_USB_MODEL_ENC=Loupedeck+
ID_USB_MODEL_ID=0002
ID_USB_SERIAL=Loupedeck_Loupedeck+
ID_USB_VENDOR=Loupedeck
ID_USB_VENDOR_ENC=Loupedeck
ID_USB_VENDOR_ID=2ec2
ID_USB_REVISION=0100
ID_USB_TYPE=generic
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:020200:0a0000:010100:010300:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_USB_DRIVER=cdc_acm
ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Miscellaneous Device
ID_USB_PROTOCOL_FROM_DATABASE=Interface Association
ID_PATH_WITH_USB_REVISION=pci-0000:c3:00.3-usbv2-0:1:1.0
ID_PATH=pci-0000:c3:00.3-usb-0:1:1.0
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_c3_00_3-usb-0_1_1_0
DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:c3:00.3-usb-0:1:1.0 /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:c3:00.3-usbv2-0:1:1.0 /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Loupedeck_Loupedeck+-if00
ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
CURRENT_TAGS=:systemd:
USEC_INITIALIZED=3562461516
Unload kernel module index.
Unloaded link configuration context.
```

Virtual machine boots up, but in the system there is no mention about this Loupedeck device. Can not find it at all.

For validating my steps, I have created a veri similar UDEV rule for an USB pen drive, and mounted it as host device which succeeded.

so my question here is: in order to use this device in win11 VM did I leave out something?
have I done something wrong? what should I do for windows to see it?

`libvirtd` version: 2023-12-17 22:51:19.342+0000: 15206: info : libvirt version: 9.10.0

`os`: Manjaro

thanks